# Unique pairs in list with duplicates & position

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

In preparation of tech interviews a friend of mine came across an interesting problem: given a list of n integers find all identical pairs and return their positions.

```
Example  input:  [3,6,6,6,1,3,1]  
Expected output: (0,5), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (4,6)
```

Stack Overflow has tons of answers regarding existence checks of unique pairs or special cases like no-duplicates, but I did not find a general, fast solution. Time complexity of my approach below is O(n) best case but degrades to O(n^2) worst case (where input values are all identical).

Is there a way to bring this down to O(n*logN) worst case?

```
// output is a vector of pairs
using TVecPairs= vector<pair<size_t,size_t>>;

TVecPairs findPairs2( const vector<uint32_t> &input ) 
{
    // map keyvalue -> vector of indices
    unordered_map<uint32_t, vector<size_t>> mapBuckets;

    // stick into groups of same value
    for (size_t idx= 0; idx<input.size(); ++idx) {
        // append index for given key value
        mapBuckets[input[idx]].emplace_back( idx );
    }

    // list of index pairs
    TVecPairs out;

    // foreach group of same value
    for (const auto &kvp : mapBuckets) { 
        const vector<size_t> &group= kvp.second;
        for (auto itor= cbegin(group); itor!=cend(group); ++itor) {
            for (auto other= itor+1; other!=cend(group); ++other) {
                out.emplace_back( make_pair(*itor,*other) );
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Assume you have input with all the same value, then enumerating solutions costs `O(n^2)`.

Comment: In the worst case you output n^2/2 pairs, so the time complexity cannot be less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have said it's a O(n^2) in case you want the output in the way that you mentioned. If you can print it a different way you can do it in O(n * (complexity of insertion/read from a hashmap) = O(n*log(n)) in C++. Some python code describing the above follows:

```
def dupes(arrlist):
   mydict=dict()
   count = 0
   for x in arrlist:
      if mydict.has_key(x):
         mydict[x] = mydict[x] + [count]
      else:
         mydict[x] = [count]
      count = count + 1
   print mydict
   return
```

And for the above example:

```
>>> dupes([3, 6, 6, 6, 1, 3, 1])
{1: [4, 6], 3: [0, 5], 6: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: And you can get from this representation to the one he expected fairly easily, I think. Though that might push it back up to O(n^2) worst case.

Comment: Yes, that representation is essentially a cartesian product of this result and hence O(n^2).

Comment: So finding duplicates is n*logn but creating the pair representation pushes it back up to quadratic worst case. Thank you for the concise sample code.